# How do you close this in Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I need to be able to close the PDF but I haven't been able to figure out how in PyPDF2 using Python 2.7

I open it below but then I try the .close():

`input1 =  PdfFileReader(open(var_loopingpath+f,"rb"))`

And get the error:

`'PdfFileReader' object has no attribute 'close'`

Thanks.

Comment: You don't "open" a PdfFileReader, you open a *stream* with the `open` command. To close the stream, save it in a variable for later use.

Answer (score 3):

Use `with` and don't bother with closing the file:

```
with open(var_loopingpath+f,"rb") as pdf_file:
    input1 = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    # rest of code
```

This way Python will close `pdf_file` when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes, the `with` statement was added in Python `2.5`.

Comment: File "PDFSplit.py", line 16, in <module>
  if x > 2: shutil.move(var_loopingpath+f,var_exceptions)
File "C:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 303, in move
  os.unlink(src)
ndowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

Comment: for f in files:
 with open(var_loopingpath+f,"rb") as pdf_file:
  input1 = PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
  #input1 =  PdfFileReader(open(var_loopingpath+f,"rb"))
  x = input1.getNumPages()
  if x > 2: shutil.move(var_loopingpath+f,var_exceptions)
  else: output.addPage(input1.getPage(0))
  outputStream = file(var_outputpath+f, "wb")
  output.write(outputStream)
  outputStream.close()